# oracle connect by multiple parents

Tags: oracle, connect-by

I am facing an issue using connect by.

I have a query through which I retrieve a few columns including these three:

- ID
- ParentID
- ObjectID

Now for the same `ID` and `parentID`, there are multiple objects associated e.g.

ID ParentID ObjectID
1      0                     112
1      0                     113
2      0                     111
2      0                     112
3      1                     111
4      1                     112

I am trying to use `connect by` but I'm unable to get the result in a proper hierarchy. I need it the way it is showed below. Take an `ID`-`parentID` combo, display all rows with that `ID-parentID` and then all the children of this `ID` i.e. whose `parentID`=`ID`


ID ParentID ObjectID
1      0                     112
1      0                     113
3      1                     111
4      1                     112
2      0                     111
2      0                     112

```
select ID,parent_id, object_id from table start with parent_id=0 
connect by prior id=parent_id order by id,parent_id
```

Above query is not resulting into proper hierarchy that i need.

Comment: The input is `0`? and you want first two level of childs? I don't understand what you are tring to achieve.

Comment: @FlorinGhita I want to get data in hierarchical format. But thing is along with ID and Parent ID , i can have multiple object ID. How to use connect by in this scenario.

Comment: I think you need nested query. Inner query will give the Id and Parent Id combination and the outer query will fetch all related records.

Comment: @padmarag i am using nested query.Inner query will result into three columns data as shown above. But after that i am unable to apply connectby to get the exact hierarchical structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Thanks to all who tried helping me.

Finally i changed my approach as applying hierarchy CONNECT BY clause to inner queryw ith multiple joins was not working for me.

I took following approach

1. Get the hierarchical data from First table i.e. table with ID-ParentID. Select Query table1 using CONNECT BY. It will give the ID in proper sequence.
   Join the retrieved List of ID.
2. Pass the above ID as comma seperated string in select query IN Clause to second table with ID-ObjectID.

> select * from table2 where ID in (above Joined string of ID) order by
>   instr('above Joined string of ID',ID);

`ORDER BY INSTR` did the magic. It will give me the result ordered by the IN Clause data and IN Clause string is prepared using the hierarchical query. Hence it will obviously be in sequence.

Again Thanks all for the help!

Note: Above approach has one constraint : ID passed as comma separated string in IN Clause. IN Clause has a limit of characters inside it. I guess 1000 chars. Not sure. 
But as i am sure on the data of First table that it will not be so much so as to cross limit of 1000 chars. Hence i chose above approach.

Answer (score 4):

Well, your problem appears to be that you are using a non-normalized table design.  If a given `ID` always has the same `ParentID`, that relationship shouldn't be indicated separately in all these rows.

A better design would be to have a single table showing the parent child relationships, with `ID` as a primary key, and a second table showing the mappings of `ID` to `ObjectID`, where I presume both columns together would comprise the primary key.  Then you would apply your hierarchical query against the first table, and join the results of that to the other table to get the relevant objects for each row.

You can emulate this with your current table structure ...

```
with parent_child as (select distinct id, parent_id from table),
     tree as (select id, parent_id from parent_child
               start with parent_id = 0
               connect by prior id = parent_id )
select id, table.parent_id, table.object_id
  from tree join table using (id)
```

Comment: But you're losing the ordering, which is what I assume is what the OP really cares about; your query is equivalent (with the OP's data) to just `select * from table`.

Comment: You can, though, include `rownum as rn` in the select from `parent_child`, and then finally `order by rn, table.object_id`. Which has saved me from having to post the similar answer I was working on.

Comment: @DaveCosta I have table design same as you mentioned. First table with ID and ParentID. Second table with ID and ObjectID. I had already tried the approach of first getting hierarchical query from First table and then joining it with second table. But in this approach, the hierarchical sequence was lost. It was n't returning the values as per hierarchy. Hence i raised this question to apply hierarchy on the joined data.

Comment: @AlexPoole -- when I tried it as shown above, it came out in the order that the OP indicated he was looking for

Comment: @RS Well, I responded to the information you posted, which doesn't indicate any of that.  The query that you show in the question has an `ORDER BY` clause that explicitly sorts the rows on `ID` -- why are you doing this if that's not the ordering you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that runs. Not ideal but will work -

```
select * from (select distinct test.id,
                    parent_id,
                    object_id,
                    connect_by_root test.id root
      from test
     start with test.parent_id = 0
    connect by prior test.id = parent_id)
order by root,id
```